# How to give wheat to a hungry follower?

Tags: godus

My follower showed minus wheat, and I didn't know how to feed him. He had good strength. Eventually he died. I had plenty of wheat, but how could I have given it to him?

Answer (score 1):

He was probably stuck without a path home, or at least a path that he recognized.

In the iPad version, after you tap a follower, the left button on the bottom of the screen "boosts" him (regenerates his stamina) for either free, or 1 wheat.